# Как в Larvel обратиться в методе контроллера к другому контроллеру и передать туда параметр?

Tags: php, laravel

```
class SendController extends Controller {

 public function send(Request $request){
        $number=$request->number; //параметр,который нужно передать
 }

}
```

Из этого контроллера нужно передать параметр `$number` в следующий контроллер

```
  class GetController extends Controller {

     public function get(Request $request){
            $param=$request->number; //параметр,который нужно получить
     }

    }
```

Как в методе `send` контроллера `SendController` обратить к методу `get` контроллера `GetController` и передать туда параметр `$number` ?

Comment: а что директиву `use` запретили?

Comment: Это не очень хорошо, но лучше, хотя бы, редиректить

Comment: Я как раз редирект и имел в виду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При необходимости перехода от одного action к другому в рамках одного или разных контроллеров, лучше всего использовать редирект, например, так:

```
class SendController extends Controller {

 public function send(Request $request){
        $number=$request->number; //параметр,который нужно передать
 return Redirect::route('route.name',array('number' => $number)) //route.name заменяем на нужное нам
 }

}
```